# Windows can't setup ad hoc connection

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

I have a Dell laptop with Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit. I want to create an ad hoc internet connection to share the internet connection from laptop to mobile, but it says: `Windows could not setup the myConnectionName.` and there is no error number or description.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your mobile device has support for the Ad Hoc network connection mode.

Please find additional information and troubleshooting notes at Microsoft's website: [Microsoft Windows 7: Setup Ad Hoc Network](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Set-up-a-computer-to-computer-ad-hoc-network)

Answer (score 0):

Once you've click create the ad-hoc network button, you should simultaneously scan and connect to this network from your mobile device. Since most android-based network doesn't support ad-hoc connections, you could also try to type "netsh wlan start hostednetwork" in command prompt to share your connection, which create an infrastructure network rather than ad-hoc network.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your wifi is turned on, i know this sound evident but sometime it's just too evident that we miss it.

If that still doesn't work, try to make one with the command shell by :

- Press Windows key (or hit the left bottom windows button)
- Write "CMD" in the search box
- right click the first option in "Programs" and hit the option "Run as administrator", that will open a black window
- Write `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=myCoolNetwork key=qwerty123456789` then press enter
- If the previous command worked, write : `netsh wlan start hostednetwork` and press enter

If these two instructions worked without any error, you should get in your wifi list a new option called : "myCoolNetwork" with the password : "qwerty123456789"

> *(Can the person downvoting gives a valid reason so i can improve my answer ? Thanks.)*